# getting first Letter of string in angularJS when retrieving data from database

Tags: angularjs

In the following script, I am able to get the first letter of string using anularJS.

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp',[]);
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope) {
$scope.myString = "kashif Riaz";
$scope.slicedString = $scope.myString.slice(0,1);
 });
```

```html
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
{{slicedString}}
</div>
```

But Actually my data is coming from database , and here i am unable to get the first letter of string ( which are contact Names).
here is an example of my approach.

```js
app.controller("myCtrl",function($scope,$http) {
$http.post(
 "names.php",
 {'id':$scope.id}
).then(function(response) {
$scope.names = response.data;
$scope.fLetter = $scope.names.list.slice(0,1);
})
});
```

In the Last line of above code , ($scope.names.list.slice(0,1) , the **list** is a name of column in mysql table.

Comment: Did you check whether you get the response correctly?

Comment: Yes . Response is ok

Comment: Not sure what is your problem here. But any way you don't need `slice()` to get the first letter. You can get the first character in a string using `charAt()` method.In your case `$scope.names.list.charAt(0)`.

Comment: `$scope.names.list` you sure you have a value in here ? you can do a GET no need of post

Comment: hmm...  **$scope.names.list**  is retrieving no value. But how it will be possible ...? I also used  **GET**  method. but nothing happened.Please find a solution

Comment: Do a console log of `response.data` and check what you actually get.

Comment: Yeah , I have got a solution using custom filter. below , I am mentioning

Answer (score 0):

I have got a solution of my own question. that how to get first letter of a string by using a custom filter

```js
var app = angular.module("myapp",[]);
app.filter('myFormat', function() {
    return function(x) {
    return x.slice(0,1);
        
    };
});

app.controller("ctrl",function($scope,$http) {
$http.post(
  "practicephp.php",
  {'email':'kashfi@gmail.com','category':'mobileNumbers'}
).then(function(response) {
 $scope.lists = response.data;
});
});
```

```html
<ul ng-repeat= "x in lists">
<li>{{x.list_name | myFormat}}</li>
</ul>
```

Thank you for people who participate in my question to help me